# Why does the contigency table Bayes Factor test does not behave like an omnibus test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, contingency-tables, bayes-factors

I have a contigency table and want to know whether the distributions differ between columns. For example, let's say I want to know whether the distribution of children with academic vs. non-academic parents differs between different schools. First, I have collected data at two schools and perform a contigency table Bayes Factor test that shows strong evidence for different distributions between these two schools.

```
library(BayesFactor)

ctable <- matrix(c(108, 72,
                   159, 21),
                 ncol=2,
                 byrow=T,
                 dimnames=list(school=LETTERS[1:2], parents=c("academic", "non-academic")))

contingencyTableBF(ctable, sampleType="indepMulti", fixedMargin="rows" )
```

Output:

```
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 33542933 ±0%

Against denominator:
  Null, independence, a = 1 
---
Bayes factor type: BFcontingencyTable, independent multinomial
```

However, if I add further rows to the contigency table (so after continuing data collections at more schools), the evidence for different distributions between schools vanishes.

```
ctable_ext <- matrix(c(108, 72,
                       159, 21,
                       136, 44,
                       129, 51,
                       142, 38,
                       129, 51,
                       143, 37,
                       136, 44,
                       145, 35,
                       138, 42,
                       139, 41),
                     ncol=2,
                     byrow=T,
                     dimnames=list(school=LETTERS[1:11], parents=c("academic", "non-academic")))

contingencyTableBF(ctable_ext, sampleType="indepMulti", fixedMargin="rows" )
```

Output:

```
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Non-indep. (a=1) : 0.7131625 ±0%

Against denominator:
  Null, independence, a = 1 
---
Bayes factor type: BFcontingencyTable, independent multinomial
```

I am surprised by this finding as I would have expected the Bayes Factor test to behave like an omnibus test (as it is the case with its frequentist counterpart, the chi-squared test). But then adding additional rows should not affect our conclusion, as the distribution between the first two schools still differs. Or am I missing something here? Can somebody explain why adding more data decreases the evidence?

Comment: Does the Bayes' factor involve a prior distribution, or is it simply a likelihood ratio?  If there is a prior involved then this might be driving the result.  Is it simple enough to perform this calculation by hand to verify that R is doing what you expect it to?

Comment: The Bayes Factor here is a simple likelihood ratio. This contigency table test is too complex for me to implement it by hand though

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page on [Bayes' Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) has a nice example using a binomial proportion.  This example indicates that the Bayes' factor does incorporate prior beliefs and, depending on these beliefs, can produce a "non-significant" result where a frequentist approach would produce a "significant" result.  A uniform prior does not guarantee the Bayes' factor to be in agreement with the frequentist likelihood ratio test.  Perhaps this is what is happening in your case.

In your first data set

$\text{Academic 1:  }108 (40.4\%) \text{  } 159 (59.6\%)$

$\text{Academic 2:  }\hspace{2.5mm}72 (77.4\%)  \text{   }\hspace{2.5mm}  21 (22.9\%)$

In your second data set

$\text{Academic 1:  }108 (7.2\%) \text{  } 159 (10.6\%)... 139 (9.2\%)$
$\text{Academic 2:  }72 (15.1\%)  \text{   } \hspace{4mm} 21 (4.4\%)...\hspace{2mm}41 (8.6\%)$

In the second data set most of the proportions are close to 8%.  Perhaps the likelihood is not strong enough to overcome the prior.

Comment: Thank you! My question is not so much about differences between Bayesian vs. frequentist tests but more about why the two Bayes Factor tests give different results (while intuitively, if the distribution between the first two rows differs, it should still differ after adding rows).

Comment: Perhaps the prior is having a different effect in each case.  In the first case the parameter space is of a smaller dimension and the proportions in each category are "flip-flopped" so the likelihood can overcome the prior.  In the second case the parameter space is of a larger dimension and most of the proportions are not all that dissimilar between the two groups so that the likelihood cannot overcome the prior.